# What does MS mean by "implementing the query yourself" for simple select optimization?

Tags: sql, performance, optimization, sql-server-ce

In this Technet article on [Query Performance Tuning](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms172984(v=SQL.110).aspx) the final section states:

> **Query Only When You Must**
>
> The SQL Server Compact query processor is a powerful tool for querying data stored in your relational database. However, there is an intrinsic cost associated with any query processor. It must compile, optimize, and generate an execution plan before it starts doing the real work of performing the plan. This is particularly true with simple queries that finish quickly. Therefore, **implementing the query yourself can sometimes provide vast performance** improvement. If every millisecond counts in your critical component, we recommend that you consider the alternative of implementing the simple queries yourself. For large and complex queries, the job is still best left to the query processor.
>
> For example, suppose you want to look up the customer ID for a series of orders arranged by their order IDs. There are two ways to accomplish this. First, you could follow these steps for each lookup:
>
> 1. Open the Orders base table
> 2. Find the row, using the specific "Order ID"
> 3. Retrieve the "Customer ID"
>
> Or you could issue the following query for each lookup:
>
> SELECT "Customer ID" FROM Orders WHERE "Order ID" =
>
> The query-based solution is simpler but slower than the manual solution, because the SQL Server Compact query processor translates the declarative SQL statement into the same three operations that you could implement manually. Those three steps are then performed in sequence. Your choice of which method to use will depend on whether simplicity or performance is more important in your application.

What is meant by the 'manual implementation' of this query? I have a simple table with contact information and want to lookup the contacts by phone number on an incoming call. This is done for many users and often and it needs to be fast (or, if possible to optimize the query such that I get the same performance but on hardware that is twice as cheap then that is nice too).

Comment: Not sure if this question is actually elementary but my Google Fu is letting me down here since searching for anything with "SQL manual implementation" obviously leads to many manuals but nothing that will remotely answer my question.

Comment: I think it is clear from the example. In order to "implement the query yourself" you are writing .NET code to retrieve the contents of the table, iterate through the rows, stopping where the orderID equals some value, and returning the CustomerID. OR, you could issue a single SQL statement to the DB engine, and have it find that data for you, but according to this snippet, that would be slower than the previous method due to the fact that the comact engine has to compile the query.

Comment: This question relates specifically to SQL Server Compact and should be tagged as such.

Comment: @SQLDiver I added the tag. Do you believe the statement are different for SQL Server 2012?

Comment: @Jeremy You are probably right. Your interpretation makes sense. However I rejected it initially because while-looping thought the rows in .net code could not possibly be faster in my mind than just using the query. If this is indeed the correct interpretation (looping the cursor through the records) would you have expected this to be faster? And could you speculate/explain why?

Comment: The quoted article does not relate to SQL Server - only SQL Server Compact.

Comment: @SpaghettiCook for regular SQL Server, I wouldn't dream of doing things the way they specify in this article. SQLDiver is correct that this advice applies ONLY to the compact edition.